# Kafka transactions not working in version 2.3.1

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Recently upgraded our kafka cluster from Kafka version 0.10.1 to 2.3.1 
I've confirmed the version has updated using the following command:

```
/home/wrte/install/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
2.3.1.1_212.11 (Commit:8c923fb4c62a38ae)
```

However I'm unable to use the transactional features as the producer fails with

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support ADD_PARTITIONS_TO_TXN
```

When I double checked the broker api version, it says transactions aren't supported:

```
/home/wrte/install/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:4443 | grep -i txn
EndTxn(26): UNSUPPORTED,
WriteTxnMarkers(27): UNSUPPORTED,
TxnOffsetCommit(28): UNSUPPORTED,
AddPartitionsToTxn(24): UNSUPPORTED,
AddOffsetsToTxn(25): UNSUPPORTED,
```

So it looks like the kafka broker still thinks its on 0.10.1 maybe? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you change the log format version? Did the transactions topic get created?

Comment: Well I have set inter.broker.protocol.version to 2.3.1, which I believe would be used as the log format version as well. I do see a new topic named __transaction_state created. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, those are correct. How many times did you restart the broker? I believe the upgrade guide says at least twice. And you can look at the jar files in the Kafka install directory to see which versions are available

Comment: I believe I've restarted multiple times. Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Have you tried starting a 2.3.1 broker locally and separate, and running the same commands?

Comment: @seriousgeek Wouldn't `kafka-topics --version` show you the client version, not the server's? Can you confirm that running broker(s) use the right jar (from the expected path)? `$ ps ax | grep -i kafka`